# How can I access mails from Shared mailbox using Mailkit

Tags: oauth-2.0, shared, mailkit, mailbox

Recently Microsoft has started to authenticate user with OAuth 2.0 protocol. I have implemented it in Asp.net Core C# and got token.

Now I am able to access mails from main mail Inbox using Mailkit from Microsoft exchange server using OAuth 2.0. But how can I be able to access mails from shared mailbox?

In my code I have mentioned shared mailbox account id.

My code is as follows

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5qYu.png)
Getting exception as "**Autheticated but not connected**". Please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to give shared mailbox permissions to OAuth app as well and shared mailbox will be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The "Authenticated but not connected" error is unique to Microsoft Exchange IMAP servers and means that your account is not authorized to connect via IMAP.

You will need to be granted permissions for IMAP access by the admin of your tenant.

Comment: Thanks Jeffery for your reply. IMAP access is already granted to tenant and I am already able to access emails. The only issue is with Shared Mailboxes.

Comment: Make sure that the shared mailbox *also* has IMAP access rights.

Comment: IMAP access rights are already granted for shared mailbox also